# AppStateManager cannot be resolved - Cloud Save

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am having trouble adding Cloud Save to my app.  I have already added Leaderboards and Achievements so my Activity extends `BaseGameActivity`.  These are the links I am following:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/CollectAllTheStars/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/catt/SaveGame.java

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/cloudsave#conflicts

However, when I, for example, type this code taken directly from the sample `AppStateManager.update(getApiClient(), OUR_STATE_KEY, mSaveGame.toBytes());` There is an error on `AppStateManager` and `getApiClient()`. AppStateManager cannot be resolved and getApiClient() is undefined for MainActivity.

I think part of the problem is that `import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager;` does not exist is my google play services library.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was update the `BaseGame` library and the `GooglePlayServices` library.

Answer (score 1):

the library **basegameutils**  had **updated** :

check this link :

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils

`AppStateManager` is deprecated now.